# Salvando arquivo automaticamente VBA

Tags: vba

Galera fiz essa macro para criar pastas e subpastas automaticamente, porem preciso que salve o arquivo que estou editando dentro da pastar criada... alguem pode me ajudar?

Segue o script

```
' MACRO PARA CRIAR PASTA DE ANO/MES/DIA

Public Const sCaminho = ""
Dim Pasta As New FileSystemObject

Public Function fnccriardiretorio(data As Date)
If Pasta.FolderExists(sCaminho & "\" & Format(data, "yyyy")) Then
    fncmes (data)
Else
    Pasta.CreateFolder (sCaminho & "\" & Format(data, "yyyy"))
    fncmes (data)
End If


End Function

Public Function fncmes(data As Date)
If Pasta.FolderExists(sCaminho & "\" & Format(data, "yyyy") & _
"\" & Format(data, "mmmm")) Then
    Call fncdia(data)
Else
    Pasta.CreateFolder (sCaminho & "\" & Format(data, "yyyy") & _
"\" & Format(data, "mmmm"))
    Call fncdia(data)
End If
End Function

Public Function fncdia(data As Date)
If Pasta.FolderExists(sCaminho & "\" & Format(data, "yyyy") & _
"\" & Format(data, "mmmm") & "\" & Format(data, "dd")) Then

Else
    Pasta.CreateFolder (sCaminho & "\" & Format(data, "yyyy") & _
"\" & Format(data, "mmmm")) & "\" & Format(data, "dd")
End If


End Function
Sub chamafuncao()
Dim data As Date
data = InputBox("Entre com a Data _EX DD/MM/AAAA")
Call fnccriardiretorio(data)
End Sub
```

Comment: Para salvar um objeto do tipo Workbook, utilize o método [SaveAs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbook-saveas-method-excel) e um Document, o método [SaveAs2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/vba/word-vba/articles/document-saveas2-method-word)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para salvar o próprio arquivo no formato xlsm na pasta que você criou, você pode usar o método SaveAs do Workbook.

```
fname = (sCaminho & "\" & Format(data, "yyyy") & _
"\" & Format(data, "mmmm")) & "\" & Format(data, "dd") & _
"\" & "nomedoarquivo"

Workbook.SaveAs FileName:=fname, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
```

Comment: esse comando ficaria dentro do Sub, certo?

Comment: Sim, ficaria dentro da função `chamafuncao()`, após a criação do diretório.